# Should CString's GetBufferSetLength() have a matching ReleaseBuffer() call?

Tags: c++, string, mfc, atl

According to the MSDN documentation for CString's [`GetBufferSetLength()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/614k79sd.aspx), a call to that method should be followed by a matching call to `ReleaseBuffer()`.

However, in the sample code in the same page, a comment states that calling `ReleaseBuffer()` is *unnecessary*:

> ```
> CSimpleString str(pMgr);
> LPTSTR pstr = str.GetBufferSetLength(3);
> pstr[0] = _T('C');
> pstr[1] = _T('u');
> pstr[2] = _T('p');
>
> // No need for trailing zero or call to ReleaseBuffer()
> // because GetBufferSetLength() set it for us.
>
> str += _T(" soccer is best!");
> ASSERT(_tcscmp(str, _T("Cup soccer is best!")) == 0);
> ```

So, should correct code call `ReleaseBuffer()` after `GetBufferSetLength()`, or is that call unnecessary?

Comment: Why is this complicated to figure out what should be called?  It's not your fault, it's just that this part of CString stinks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes, it's much simpler and clearer with `std::wstring::resize()` :) But honestly operating with a `std::wstring` and then copying back to `CString` seems kind of overkill.

Comment: @Mr.C64 -- Well point number `2.` in your edit makes my point.  These are supposedly functions that are "well documented", but are they?  I guess not, since you're asking how to use them.  Once it gets to that stage, something really smells bad with the implementation (user's not being to figure out how to use the public interface safely).

Comment: Some claims were made that `CString` is terrible, but is there really any other library with all the `CString` features? Like conversion from ANSI/MBCS to UTF-16 and back? Conversion to `BSTR`s? Collation support? Support for embedded resources? Drop-in replacement for any C-style string? Including variable argument lists? I'm not so sure, what's terrible. Mind to elaborate?

Comment: @IInspectable: I like the rich `CString` interface. I also find the implicit conversion to const C-style string pointers convenient, even if [according to some _"modern rules"_ it's better having explicit calls](https://herbsutter.com/2012/06/21/reader-qa-why-dont-modern-smart-pointers-implicitly-convert-to/) (e.g. `std::wstring::c_str()`). However, `std::wstring` is better in that it has move semantics (better than COW under multi-threading), it can be used with STL algorithms, it's well integrated with Boost, can be used with range-for loops, etc.

Comment: @Mr.C64: You can use an explicit call to convert to a const C-style string ([CString::GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59cayc6.aspx)). You can also use a `CString` with the C++ Standard Library's algorithms, with a few iterator adapters. I'm not proposing to use `CString`s everywhere. But if your code uses them already, there's no need to change anything. Besides, there's one specific feature that makes `CString`s really stand out: They can cross DLL boundaries. Something you won't get from `std::string`, unless you are willing to impose restrictions (if you can).

Comment: @IInspectable: It's new to me that `CString`s can safely cross DLL boundaries... How are `CString`s different than other C++ classes? I thought the only safe ways at the boundaries are C functions, C++ interfaces, or COM (which is basically C++ interfaces). Of course the usual rule applies that if _all_ modules (EXE, DLLs) are built with _same_ VC++ compiler and dynamically-link to the _same_ flavor of the CRT, then C++ classes (both `CString` and `std::string`) can cross DLL boundaries (but that's an highly-constraining design).

Comment: @Mr.C64: The requirements for crossing DLL boundaries are even stronger than you explain: All modules must link against the same **copy** of the CRT to safely transfer CRT objects across DLL boundaries. Linking against the same flavor isn't sufficient. `CString`s (in ATL) can cross DLL boundaries, because the allocator is prepared for this scenario. It allocates from the process heap (vs. the CRT heap, which `std::string`s commonly do). See [Memory Management with CStringT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bww86e57.aspx) for a short introduction.

Comment: @IInspectable: With _"flavor"_ I meant something like "VS2010's release-build CRT DLL", so (unless I'm missing something) what I meant is what you call _"copy"_. Interesting note on ATL `CString` crossing DLL boundaries thanks to custom string manager that allocates from process heap. Thanks. BTW I think it's possible to specify custom allocators for `std::string` as well, although I'm not sure the rest of the STL infrastructure supports crossing boundaries of DLLs/EXEs built with different compiler versions (since the STL classes implementations changed e.g. from VS2010 to VS2012).

Comment: @Mr.C64: The allocator for `std::basic_string` is a template parameter. If you want to use a custom allocator, you wind up with a different type. For that to work across DLL boundaries, all participating modules have to agree on your custom type. Enforcing this restriction is no easier than having all participating modules use the same copy of the CRT.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `ReleaseBuffer` is to sync the state of the C-style string that the buffer contains with the state of the `CString` internal variables. Presumably this is just getting the final string length and storing it internally, and perhaps reallocating the buffer if there's a large discrepancy.

In the case of the example, the string length was stated to be exactly 3 characters. Since the size of the string didn't change via manipulation of the buffer, there's no need to update the length after that manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`CSimpleStringT::GetBufferSetLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getbuffersetlength) is unambiguously clear:

> If you use the pointer returned by [`CSimpleStringT::GetBufferSetLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getbuffersetlength) to change the string contents, call `ReleaseBuffer` to update the internal state of `CSimpleStringT` before you use any other `CSimpleStringT` methods.

Sample code is not contractual. In the event, where sample code contradicts the formal specification, go with the formal specification. The sample code in the documentation is written against a particular implementation detail that's not part of the contract. The formal specification is contractual.

---

Since the documentation is a bit shallow on explaining why those class members exist at all, here is some rationale to understand the particular problem they solve, and learn why the rules are the way they are:

Classes typically have a set of properties that always hold. Those are *invariants*. Class member implementations are allowed to temporarily violate those invariants, but when they return, all invariants must have been restored. Client code as well as class implementations rely on those invariants.

For sake of illustration, let's assume a simplified `CString` implementation that stores two pieces of information: A length value and a pointer to a character array. Its invariant is that the pointer will always point to a character array of `length` characters followed by a NUL terminator. It is established once a class instance has been constructed, and maintained for each call to its public interface. (The actual `CStringT` class template stores *a lot* more state that needs to remain consistent.)

Occasionally, particularly when interfacing with C code, it becomes necessary to put an object into a state where invariants aren't maintained. This allows a C API to write directly into a buffer that's managed by a C++ class, reducing the overhead of allocating a temporary buffer, possibly resizing the internal buffer, and then copying everything over. That's the main use case for `GetBuffer` and `GetBufferSetLength`. Once a value has been returned, the class no longer promises to maintain any invariants. A consequence of this is that it is no longer allowed to call any members of the public interface, until the invariants have been restored. That's the purpose of `ReleaseBuffer`.

Mind you, there's *a lot* of state that needs to remain consistent. For example, `CStringT` maintains a capacity alongside the string length in an attempt to reduce allocations. It implements short-string optimization, and supports shared ownership with copy-on-write semantics. If you decide to be clever and skip over the mandatory call to `ReleaseBuffer` (like the author of the sample), all those invariants instantly become your responsibility.

A final note on whether it is or isn't allowed to call [`ReleaseBufferSetLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#releasebuffersetlength) in place of `ReleaseBuffer`: I believe they are functionally equivalent for all values of `nNewLength` other than `-1`. The documentation is somewhat fuzzy here, calling them *"functionally similar"*, though I think this is more of an issue with the wording rather than a hint towards an actual difference.

---

*Note: It is not required for an implementation to fail, when used without following it's documented protocol. As a consequence, you cannot test, whether all steps of that protocol are required.*

Comment: But the included sample code explicitly states the _opposite_ in a comment (_"// No need for trailing zero or call to ReleaseBuffer() because GetBufferSetLength() set it for us."_), so the whole doc is _not_ clear. Either there's a bug in the paragraph or in the code snippet comment.

Comment: @Mr.C64: Sample code is never contractual. It may have been correct at some point but was never updated. It's the prose that counts.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine a situation where you'd call `GetBufferSetLength` and *not* change the string contents. I wonder if they really meant to say "string length" instead of "string contents"?

Comment: @MarkRansom: I posted a quote from the formal specification. In all likeliness, in the current implementation for the currently supported platforms, there is no technical reason to call `ReleaseBuffer` in case you aren't changing the length. The specification allows the implementation to change that. That's unlikely to ever happen, since apparently there is confusion on whether or not sample code is contractual, so it is being abused. Still, the formal specification is clear on the subject. If you want to write safe code, you should go by the documentation.

Comment: I certainly can't argue that point, I'm just wondering aloud if it isn't just a bug *in the documentation*. It wouldn't be the first time that happened - Microsoft's docs don't go through the rigorous vetting that the C++ standard gets for example. The person writing the documentation is almost certainly not the person who is responsible for the class behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Although the MFC documentation is consistently lower quality than even the Windows API documentation, I'd still say that the wording was consciously chosen. One could have spelled out the special cases, under which calling `ReleaseBuffer` is not strictly required. That would only allow developers to write *"clever"* code, occasionally omitting a call to `ReleaseBuffer`. It'd both be harder to read, and needlessly limit future evolution of the `CString` class. Instead, the specification kept things simple, in exchange for requiring an occasional (technically) superfluous call.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for sharing your opinions and thanks @MarkRansom for interesting comments and reply as well. I assume calling `ReleaseBufferSetLength` instead of `ReleaseBuffer` and passing the explicit length would be fine as well, right?

Comment: As a side note, it would be interesting to know if `ReleaseBufferSetLength(len)` and `ReleaseBuffer(len)` are the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.C64: `ReleaseBufferSetLength` and `ReleaseBuffer` are not the same thing, and only `ReleaseBuffer` is documented to perform the necessary bookkeeping when done with the buffer returned from any of the `GetBuffer` methods. Since `ReleaseBufferSetLength` doesn't provide any functionality that `ReleaseBuffer` wouldn't, it's not a limitation either. At a guess I would assume, that the redundancy is a leftover of the merge between ATL and MFC, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @IInspectable The [documentation for `ReleaseBufferSetLength()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4hy2txf.aspx) clearly states it's functionally equivalent to `ReleaseBuffer()`, except you must pass the final string length.

Comment: @Mr.C64: What it really says is *"This function is functionally **similar** to ReleaseBuffer"*. Unfortunately, the documentation goes on to name one (of several) differences, suggesting that this were the only difference. It isn't. Even if it were, the documentation for the `GetBufferXxx` is explicitly asking you to call `ReleaseBuffer` (and only that class member). So whether the implementations are equivalent or not is a moot point. Don't call `ReleaseBufferSetLength` after working with the internal buffer of a `CString` (it doesn't offer any unique functionality anyway).

Comment: @IInspectable: It sounds like the official ATL documentation needs some update and fixes. I saw several well-working code calling `ReleaseBufferSetLength(len)` and assuming it's equivalent to `ReleaseBuffer(len)`. If they are not equivalent, what's the point of having `ReleaseBufferSetLength()` at all?

Comment: @Mr.C64: Calling anything but the required `ReleaseBuffer` will have undefined behavior. Appearing to succeed is a valid form of undefined behavior, but it's still undefined. *"what's the point of having `ReleaseBufferSetLength()` at all?"* - As I noted earlier, it's likely a leftover of the merge between ATL and MFC string classes. They started out as completely different, unrelated libraries at some point, and had to both carry their legacy over to the merged version. The point of having both methods is to not break existing code.